# Is there an equivalent of `console.table` in the browser?

Tags: javascript

[`console.table`](https://plus.google.com/+AddyOsmani/posts/PmTC5wwJVEc) does exactly what I need it to do. But I want that table to be outputted in the browser. How can I do this?

I've tried a few other solutions that didn't work because either:

1. They expect an array of objects.
2. The columns aren't dynamically determined (i.e. my objects don't all have the props).

My Object looks like this:

```
{
  source0: {target0: 2, target1: 2, target2: 1},
  source1: {target1: 3},
  /*...*/
}
```

Comment: what is `console.table`?

Comment: I wouldn't be a one-liner but is there really a problem in iterating to list the columns and then build the table with a second iteration ? Are you expecting us to write that code or do you see a blocking problem ?

Comment: First off, thanks for teaching me a new debugging tool :) Secondly, you should use a templating system for this. Mustache.js maybe?

Comment: @Jamiec: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/tips-and-tricks#console-table

Comment: Even if I could inspect the dev tools and grab the table's html I would be happy at this point @dystroy

Comment: You're welcome @AlexanderBrevig. Not sure I really want the hassle of that when `console.table` has already done what I need, I just need the HTML from that.

Comment: @Jamiec - It's part of the [Firebug Console API](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API#console.table.28data.5B.2C_columns.5D.29). Of course, Firebug does run in the browser so the OP possibly wants a JavaScript library to generate HTML tables from arbitrary variables.

Comment: Well, I guess the answer is:  You can't get the HTML from `console.table`, so you have to build your own solution.

Comment: console.log().....? with firebug super

Comment: FYI - I rewrote my Handlebars solution to fit your requirements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution, with two iterations, the first one to find the columns and the second one to build the table :

```
var s = {
  source0: {target0: 2, target1: 2, target2: 1},
  source1: {target1: 3},
}

var cols = [];
for (var k in s) {
  for (var c in s[k]) {
    if (cols.indexOf(c)===-1) cols.push(c);
  }
}
var html = '<table><tr>'+
    cols.map(function(c){ return '<th>'+c+'</th>' }).join('')+
    '</tr>';
for (var l in s) {
  html += '<tr>'+
      cols.map(function(c){ return '<td>'+(s[l][c]||'')+'</td>' }).join('')+
      '</tr>';
}
html += '</table>';
```

[demonstration](http://jsbin.com/zewatujaxa/1/)

Of course you'd have to tailor it for your exact need. [For example if you want to have the keys of the properties](http://jsbin.com/huqidokusi/2/edit).

Comment: This does not include the "source0" and "source1"

Comment: @AlexanderBrevig If that's needed, then it's a simple change, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a templating system for this.

Here is an example with Handlebars.js http://jsfiddle.net/x6r5fbw1/ (you can also run snippet below)

```js
    $(function(){
        var data = {
          source0: {target0: 2, target1: 2, target2: 1},
          source1: {target1: 3},
        },
        table = [],
        colsDict = {},
        key = "",
        innerKey = "",
        tableData = [],
        tmp = Handlebars.compile($("#template").text()),
        html = "";
    
        for (key in data) {
          if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            table.push({title:key});
            for (innerKey in data[key]){
              if (data[key].hasOwnProperty(innerKey)) {
                table[table.length-1][innerKey] = data[key][innerKey];
                colsDict[innerKey] = ""; } } } }
    
        var cols = ["title"];
        for (key in colsDict){
          if (colsDict.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            cols.push(key); } }
          
        for (key in table){
          var obj = {};
          for (innerKey in cols){
            if (table[key].hasOwnProperty(cols[innerKey])) {
              obj[cols[innerKey]] = table[key][cols[innerKey]]; }
            else{
              obj[cols[innerKey]] = ""; } }
          tableData.push(obj); }     
    
        html = tmp({cols: cols, rows:tableData});
        $("#target").html(html);
    });
```

```html
    <div id="target"></div>
    <script language="text/template" id="template">
        <table>
            <tr>
            {{#each cols}}
                <th>{{this}}</th>
            {{/each}}
            </tr>
            {{#each rows}}
            <tr>
                {{#each this}}
                <td>{{this}}</td>
                {{/each}}
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </table>
    </script>
    
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.0.0/handlebars.js"></script>
```

Comment: In this costly and heavy solution you still need to hard code the columns. I doubt OP would find this useful.

Comment: As @dystroy has said I don't want to hardcode the columns.

Comment: So, you won't know all columns until you've inspected all properties in all `data.properties`? This will not be as easy as you may think

Comment: Rewrote to match requirements. Interesting puzzle

Comment: I prefer @dystroy's solution, but thanks. I'll vote your solution up too :)